# Algorithm to increase or decrease with proximity to x

Tags: calculus

If I have an array of arbitrary values such as [0.66, 0.83, 1, 1.17, 1.34] and want to increase/decrease the values with proximity to 1 by an arbitrary coefficient.

**Edit**: In one scenario I might want to increase the difference between the values. That would mean 0.66 would be significantly smaller, 0.83 less significantly smaller. Values >1 would go the other way, so 1.34 would go significantly up, and 1.17 would also go up but less significantly.

In a different scenario I might want the opposite so 0.66 would move significantly towards 1 and 0.83 would move less significantly towards 1. and 1.17 would go towards 1, but less significantly than 1.34.

Is there a formula I can use to achieve this by changing a coefficient in the formula?

Comment: Hi David, I think your question may be a little hard to understand in its current form. See if you can add to it to make the actual question a little more clear. It may help to provide an example of what you are looking for.

Comment: There are many different things you could do. (A) replace $x=1+t$ by $x=1+\lambda t$ for some fixed $0<\lambda<1$. So if you chose $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}$ then $1.5$ would be replaced by $1.25$ and $0.6$ would be replaced by $0,8$. (B) you could modify (A) by only making the replacement if $|t|<k$ for some fixed $k$. (C) you could make the factor $\lambda$ smaller for values closer to 1 (so that they were more strongly "attracted" to 1. But you need to add to the question to provide more guidance on what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have tried to clearify the question above.